# Matching with re module

Tags: python

Some words may not necessarily end with `_v123.ext`
Such as:

```
var_a='FWPR_102_002_020-Xyz_v002.txt'
var_b='102_002_020_002_.dbl
```

Using `re` on `var_a`:

```
import re 
result = re.search(r'(\d+.\w+)$', var_a)
group=result.groups()
```

But with `var_b` returning `None` it crashes throwing an AttributeError:

`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'`

The expression should only return if a basename ends with with `_v` (can be lower and capital) followed with one or more digits that proceed a period separating the file extension from a basename.

Comment: .added underscore... try now...

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: `None` is returned when there's no match. You should handle it with `if` statement.

Comment: @Sputnix notice I've edited my answer a bit.

Comment: You could also use a formal grammar for matching, e.g. [`parsley`](http://parsley.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#from-regular-expressions-to-grammars) (not that I think you should in this case, because it seems far simpler to use regex, but people are usually not aware of that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `os` to get the file's base name, use `str.split` and `str.join` to remove the extension and inspect the last part, use `str.isdigit` to find out if a string only contains numbers:

```
def is_file_interesting(filename):
    if not filename:
        return None

    # remove extension 'blah.extension' -> 'blah'
    filename = ".".join(filename.split(".")[:-1])

    # last part of name 'blah_blah_v123' -> 'v123'
    last_part = os.path.basename(filename).split("_")[-1]

    # 'v1234' -> '1234'
    digit_part = last_part[1:]

    # check if actually only digits with 'v' in front
    return last_part and (last_part[0] == 'v') and digit_part.isdigit()
```

I try to avoid regex whenever possible.

Also, `v123.extension` will give `True` here, which I guess is the right handling (doesn't satisfy your condition of `'_'` before `'v'`).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!